# Having two for-loops to create a list with (i,j) where the outer loop doesn't override the inner

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, lapply

I'm trying to get to grips with lapply and loops in R. I need to rename every column in a matrix, that has arbitrary column names, into meaningful ones. The result should be like this:

```
wages.seg.mean.1996 <- rnorm(4)
wages.seg.var.1996 <- rnorm(4)
wages.seg.sd.1996 <- rnorm(4)
wages.seg.min.1996 <- rnorm(4)
wages.seg.max.1996 <- rnorm(4)
wages.seg.total.1996 <- rnorm(4)
wages.seg.mean.1997 <- rnorm(4)
wages.seg.var.1997 <- rnorm(4)
wages.seg.sd.1997 <- rnorm(4)
wages.seg.min.1997 <- rnorm(4)
wages.seg.max.1997 <- rnorm(4)
wages.seg.total.1997 <- rnorm(4)
df <-  data.frame(wages.seg.mean.1996,wages.seg.var.1996,wages.seg.sd.1996,wages.seg.min.1996,wages.seg.max.1996,wages.seg.total.1996,wages.seg.mean.1997,wages.seg.var.1997,wages.seg.sd.1997,wages.seg.min.1997,wages.seg.max.1997,wages.seg.total.1997)
```

I know how the variables are sorted, so I just need a list with all the new names in correct order, then I can do this:

```
colnames(df) <- wages.list[]  
df <- tbl_df(df)
```

In my real data the year-period is 1996-2009, but I guess this example doesn't need more than two years.
I've tried like this, but because the second loop is nested, I just end up with the last year overwriting the others:

```
wages.seg.list <- NULL 
wages.seg.list <-  list()
 for (i in 1996:1997)  {
    for (j in seq(1,12,6)) {
wages.seg.list[[j]] <-   paste0("wages.seg.mean.",i)
wages.seg.list[[j+1]]   <-   paste0("wages.seg.var.",i)
wages.seg.list[[j+2]]   <-   paste0("wages.seg.sd.",i)
wages.seg.list[[j+3]]   <-   paste0("wages.seg.min.",i)
wages.seg.list[[j+4]]   <-   paste0("wages.seg.max.",i)
wages.seg.list[[j+5]]   <-   paste0("wages.seg.total.",i)
    }
}
```

So you see how I try to vary position in the list and the name of the variable at the same time. I can do this by hand, of course, but I want to understand the logic of how to do something like this. If you could help me to get that, I would be grateful.

Emil

Comment: It looks like your `wages.seg.list` is holding the titles, but no actual data. Is that your intention? Or did you want the data held in the list, with meaningful names for the list elements, and this is just setting up the place to put them?

Comment: Well what I was  trying to accomplish was to make a vector with  the 12 (in my real data much longer of course) character-elements, where the year-stub is added to the 6 vars automatically, in the correct order., Because then I can change the arbitrary variable names in the dataset like this:
colnames(df) <- wages.seg.list[]
So  you actually accomplished that in your answers second line of code with the apply-function, which was just the kind of R-logic I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you're looking for?

You said that you wanted to know more about how to do loops in `R`, but this does the opposite. It shows how to *avoid* loops, which is one of `R`'s strengths. `R`'s vectorization means that to efficiently use `R` you have to think a bit differently to other languages. You have to spend less effort telling the computer "how" to do things, and focus on "what" you want to achieve.

#### Edit: an even more vectorized solution.

```
yearly.name.template <- c(
  "wages.seg.mean.", 
  "wages.seg.var.",
  "wages.seg.sd.",
  "wages.seg.min.",
  "wages.seg.max.",
  "wages.seg.total."
)


# create the names for your list titles.
all.names.df <- merge(yearly.name.template, 1996:1997, all=TRUE)

# apply(x,1,FUN,...) works row-wise on the data frame or matrix.
# 'collapse' is an argument to 'paste0' to merge the entire row.
all.names <- apply(all.names.df, 1, paste0, collapse="")

# now create a list of blank entries, one entry per list title.
wages.seg.list <- vector("list", length(all.names))

# and push the names in.
names(wages.seg.list) <- all.names
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! That was what I was trying to say, although not clearly formulated: I usually does this kind of  thing in Stata, and I know that looping is usually not the most effective way to do things in R. However, the logic is new to me, hard to wrap my head around. So this is great, I get what you're doing. Thanks!